# Minimizing a function - sum of squares

Tags: calculus, statistics, functions

I'm hoping you can help with this problem. I haven't taken calculus in years and I don't know where to start...

The sum of squares of a sample of data is minimized when the sample mean is used as the basis of the calculation.

$$g(c) = \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-c)^2$$

Show that the function is minimized where $c = \overline {X} $.

Comment: How do you find the minimum of a function ?

Answer (score 4):

Viewed as a function of $c$, $g(c)$ is differentiable and
$$
g'(c)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}-2(X_i-c)
$$
If this has a minimum, it must occur where $g'(c)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

We have $g(c) \ge 0$. For relative extrema $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we need:
$$
0 = g'(c) = \sum_{i=1}^n 2 (X_i - c) (-1) 
= 2 \left( n c - \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)
\Rightarrow \\
c = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \bar{X}
$$
Further
$$
g''(c) = 2n > 0
$$
so it should be a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

An arithmetic argument,

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - c)^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x} + \bar{x} - c)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2 + n (\bar{x} - c)^2 - 2 (\bar{x} - c) \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x}) \\
&\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2 ,
\end{align}
$$

since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x}) = 0$ and $n (\bar{x} - c)^2 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can know where a minimum exists by using the derivative of the function because its well known that in most of the cases the minimum value is when the a derivative of the function is zero.
So if you can find the first derivative of the function and equalized it with zero you can obtain the value that you are looking for.

Comment: That is not true: the derivative at a minimum may be undefined, or the minimum may happen at a domain endpoint where the derivative is non-zero. Since the OP hasn't "taken calculus in years" could you give more detail?

Comment: You are right, the derivative at a minimum is not always defined. And this is not the case, but its important to consider this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the derivative of $g(c)$ equal to $0$ yields:
$$
g'(c) = 2\sum_{i} (x_i - c) = 2(\sum_i x_i - nc)= 0\implies \sum_i x_i = nc \implies c^* = \frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
g(c) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-c)^2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2-2X_ic+c^2)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^nX_ic+\sum_{i=1}^nc^2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-2cn\bar{X}+nc^2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2+n(c^2-2c\bar{X})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2+n(c^2-2c\bar{X}+\bar{X}^2)-n\bar{X}^2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2+n(c-\bar{X})^2-n\bar{X}^2\\
&\ge \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-n\bar{X}^2\\
\end{array}
$

with equality
if and only if
$c=\bar{X}
$.